# CSS Text Hover & Transition Effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the ***hover effect 4*** on, 
http://miketricking.github.io/dist/.

I was able to come up with this test on jfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/34aaqh70/

Also I can't figure out how to make that auto-responsive.

If anybody knows of a video that explains this effect, please share!

My Code:

```css
*------ Basic Setup ------*/ * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: '.';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*------ Dividers ------*/

.divider {
  width: 25%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(89, 89, 89, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
.divider span {
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
/*------ DV BOX ------*/

.dv-box {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
/*------ Donation ------*/

.donate {
  padding-top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
}
.donate-content {
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.donate h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}
.donate-content .description {
  margin-top: 0%;
}
.donate-content p {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.donate img {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
.donate img:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}
/*------ Volunteer ------*/

.volunteer {
  padding-top: 5%;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.volunteer-content {
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.volunteer h1 {
  margin-bottom: -.5%;
}
.volunteer-content .description {
  margin-top: 0%;
}
.volunteer-content p {
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
.volunteer img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: .9;
}
.volunteer img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="row dv-box">

    <!--Donate-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <section class="donate" id="donate">
        <div class="donate-content">
          <h1>Donate</h1>
          <div class="divider">
            <span><i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 description">
            <p>We are always looking for people to help us!</p>
            <p>Click on the image below, to fill out the application form</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SDtdEQE.png" alt="">
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
    </div>




    <!--Volunteer-->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <section class="volunteer" id="volunteer">
        <div class="volunteer-content">
          <h1>Volunteer</h1>
          <div class="divider">
            <span><i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 description">
            <p>We are always looking for people to help us!</p>
            <p>Click on the image below, to fill out the application form</p>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Z5nGc0D.png" target="_blank" alt="form">
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this effect you want? Please check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/34aaqh70/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is you have an image with a fixed height/width sitting inside of a div set at 100%.  Try the code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/nLd80s6f/

I changed the width of the image element to 100% and tweaked the padding and margin of the overlay element to respond with the image.  I also wrapped the entire icon in an additional div (class "wrapper") and set the width to 80%.  This was just to get the icon closer to your original size.  If you toggle it off in dev tools, you'll see why I added it.

To have this icon completely responsive, you will need to add media queries to shrink the font at break points.  If you have questions about how to do that, you are welcome to ask:)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/TqiQO5M.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay">

        <a class="info" href="#">Donate</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
}

.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid #00ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
  ;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(48, 152, 157, 0.4);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  font-size: 400%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 10%;
  padding: 30% 10%;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some changes in your `html` and `css` code.
you need make change in `.hovereffect`, `.hovereffect a.info` class and add `.hovereffect a.info span` class in as below in snippet.

I hope it will helps you :)

```css
.hovereffect {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 100%;*/
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: solid #00ffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  background-color: rgba(48, 152, 157, 0.4);
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  font-weight: normal;

  margin: 5% auto;
  /*padding: 150px 80px;*/
  height:90%;
  width: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.hovereffect a.info span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/TqiQO5M.png" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <a class="info" href="#">
        <span>Donate</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```